# How can I automatically detect elements in a DOM to populate a const array?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I've written a script that pretty much works on its own, but the problem is that if I add another modal to the page, I need to get into my script to add an entry for it to be recognized by it. I want to know if there is a way to have the script automatically detect the number of modals on the page, and automatically assign them their appropriate values within my const, and then run the function on them as dictated by the script. Here is my code.

```js
// Staff Modal Element Arrays
const modalClose =  document.querySelectorAll('.modal-close');
const modalButton = document.querySelectorAll('.staff-modal-button p')
const modalMain = document.querySelectorAll('.staff-modal')

// Staff Modal Combined Definition Array
const staffModal =  {one: {button: modalButton[0], modal: modalMain[0] , close: modalClose[0]},
                    two: {button: modalButton[1], modal: modalMain[1], close: modalClose[1]},
                    three: {button: modalButton[2], modal: modalMain[2], close: modalClose[2]},
                    four: {button: modalButton[3], modal: modalMain[3], close: modalClose[3]},
                    five: {button: modalButton[4], modal: modalMain[4], close: modalClose[4]},
                    six: {button: modalButton[5], modal: modalMain[5], close: modalClose[5]},
                    seven: {button: modalButton[6], modal: modalMain[6], close: modalClose[6]}}

// Function to Define Modal Actions

function modalFunction(staffNumber) {
    const modalOpen = staffNumber.button;
    const modal = staffNumber.modal;
    const modalExit = staffNumber.close;
    modalOpen.addEventListener('click', function() {
        modal.style.display='flex';
    })
    modalExit.addEventListener('click', function() {
        modal.style.display='none';
    })
    modal.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (e.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display='none'
        }
    })
}

// Calling Functions for Each Staff Modal in Array

for (i in staffModal) {
    modalFunction(staffModal[i]);
}
```

Comment: You already use `.querySelectorAll()` to get all the modals out of the html, so you know exactly how many modals there are on the page. The clue then is making staffModal an array, so you do not have to create property names like one/two/three but can just use indexes.

Comment: @Shilly that makes total sense. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already select ALL modals with `document.querySelectorAll('.staff-modal')`. There is no need to manually write your `staffModal` object, just iterate over everything you selected:

```
for (let i = 0; i < modalMain.length; i++) {
    modalFunction({button: modalButton[i], modal: modalMain[i] , close: modalClose[i]});
}
```

Also I would not select all the elements from all modals and assume they are in the same order. I'm not sure if there actually is some weird case where they aren't, but it would be better to just select the parent modal and the children subsequently. Like this:

```
const modalMain = document.querySelectorAll('.staff-modal');

function modalFunction(modal) {
    const modalOpen = modal.querySelector('.staff-modal-button p');
    const modalExit = modal.querySelector('.modal-close');
    modalOpen.addEventListener('click', function() {
        modal.style.display='flex';
    })
    modalExit.addEventListener('click', function() {
        modal.style.display='none';
    })
    modal.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (e.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display='none'
        }
    })
}

for (let i = 0; i < modalMain.length; i++) {
    modalFunction(modalMain[i]);
}
```

Comment: This is a really good solution. My modal open elements are outside the modal parent element though, so i'll still select those as a constant, but you've saved me the hassle of selecting the modal close buttons, as they're contained in the modal parent element. Thank you so much!